# Wordpress youtube plugin - Changing feed from channel to favourites (PHP Guru required)

Tags: php, wordpress, api, youtube

I am not new to Wordpress, but new to PHP. I have managed to get the plugin working (thumbnails etc) but I cannot seem to change the default feed from the default youtube channel to my favourites. I found a post where the dev says to edit the url feed on line 268 of /core/parse.php
Which looks like this:

```
    'url' => 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$v.'/uploads?orderby=published&max-results='.$z.'&start-index='.$i,
```

I searched google high n low, I found this:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/favorites

And tried different variations of it. 0 videos imported.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/automatic-youtube-video-posts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this URL: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_favorites

The correct code would be

```
 'url' => 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$v.'/favorites?orderby=published&max-results='.$z.'&start-index='.$i,
```

Comment: Dude, I have been trying so many different variations I was starting to go crazy. Thanks so much for taking time to help me. Bulk...you are a f'ing guru!

Comment: Im not sure how to add to your rep, but thanks again! It works :)

Comment: No problem :) you can up-vote the response (up arrow to the left of my answer) and also select this answer as the correct one (think there is a tick or button also to the left).

Comment: Yup, I thought that was the case with the arrow...but me being such a noob im unable to do it (I require at least 15 points myself...doh). I have ticked the answer tho for anybody in the same boat! All the best man, I owe you!